# Form processing in templates of typo3

Tags: forms, templates, typo3

In typo3 I have a template page and it has a form with upload options. How can I express it like normal php code? I want to process the form using `$_POST`. Any suitable links or examples will helpful.

Comment: Are you using the Processing language? If not, this shouldn't be tagged with [processing]. What would a general processing tag even mean?

Comment: what template? (ts, fluid, other ?) what form? (typo3 from, powermail, fluid form? )  Process to do what?  Be more explicit

Comment: i am doing fluid template forms

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using TYPO3 ver. 4.5+ suitable link is: http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/extension_builder

You just need to create TYPO3 extension ans insert it on the page.

You can also use dirty workaround and use script name directly in the form's `action` attribute, but this way you will NOT render the processed result in the TYPO3 page...

Insert the coin, choose the flavor.